# how can I change the order of 2 divs in mobile version that their width is 100%? can I use bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

[image]I have two divs how can I change the order of them when the size of screen get smaller?
I khow we can use pull and push in bootstrap,but it dosent work here,
I want first display 4 icons then under theme logo, 
here is my code:

```
 <div class="logo col-lg-4 col-xs-12 col-sm12 col-md-12"></div>
 <div class="menu col-lg-8 col-xs-12 col-sm12 col-md-12"></div>
```

Comment: Can you provide more specific what are you trying to do here. Like providing picture maybe. :)

Comment: yes,I edit my question,

Comment: still didn't understand what you want, i mean you can provide picture how it should look like on wide, and how it should look like on smaller device. Not the big pic of what you got. and you can also insert your **not working** pull push code so we can see it.

Answer (score 0):

your question is not very clear. but I will try to help you...

if you want  for large screen    | MENU | LOGO |  for other screen widths it shows | LOGO | MENU |

```
    <div class="logo col-lg-push-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12"> logo </div>
    <div class="menu col-lg-pull-8 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12"> menu </div>
```

hope this helps

Comment: No Ig is for large screen I mean for xs screen what should I do?